# Filtering GCP dataproc batches list by createTime doesn't work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to get a list of GCP dataproc batches that have been created (succeeded/failed/running) on a specific date. But, I keep getting errors when trying to filter the results of `dataproc batches list` command using a time field.

I followed Google Cloud's documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/filtering-and-formatting-fun-with) and tried several different commands:

```
gcloud dataproc batches list --region=us-central1 --limit=1 --filter="createTime.date('%Y-%m-%d')='2023-11-01'"
gcloud dataproc batches list --region=us-central1 --limit=1 --filter="createTime.date('%Y-%m-%d',Z)='2023-11-01'"
gcloud dataproc batches list --region=us-central1 --limit=1 --filter="stateTime.date('%Y-%m-%d')='2023-11-01'"
gcloud dataproc batches list --region=us-central1 --limit=1 --filter="stateTime.date('%Y-%m-%d',Z)='2023-11-01'"
```

But, all of the commands throw an error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.batches.list) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Filter string 'createTime.date('%Y-%m-%d)>2023-11-01' is not a valid filter.
```

I followed Google Cloud's documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/resource-keys)  to identify resource keys. I tried listing all resource-keys for dataproc batches and both createTime and stateTime are resource-keys. But, when I tried

```
gcloud dataproc batches list --region=us-central1 --limit=1 --filter="createTime='2023-11-01'"
gcloud dataproc batches list --region=us-central1 --limit=1 --filter="stateTime='2023-11-01'"
```

I get an unsupported field error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.batches.list) INVALID_ARGUMENT: unsupported field 'createTime'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in the filter syntax (camel case vs snake case in filter field names), here is how you can filter out batches using gcloud:

```bash
gcloud dataproc batches list \
  --limit=5 \
  --filter='create_time<"2023-10-10" AND create_time>"2023-10-01"' \
  --format='table(name,create_time)'
```

Comment: Thanks @igor-dvorzhak that worked. I didn't realize that I needed to convert camel case field names to snake case. Thanks.